# SonarQube didn't analyse C# code

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I ran the analysis from two different machines, both submitting their reports to the same SonarQube instance? and the analysis methods, parameters are the same.

I analysed the same project on two PCs but got different results.  I have checked many settings but they were all the same.  The difference is that the C# code was excluded from the analysis results on one PC which was running Windows Server 2012(VM).
 I found that when I excute the cmd my localhost .sonarqube created output-cs, but VM doesn’t.

**Log file**
Analyzer working directory does not exist: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\F2_SQ.sonarqube\out\1\output-cs'. Analyzer results won't be loaded from this directory.

**windows server 2012 R2 Install Info is...**
sonarqube-6.7.1 | sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778 | sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.0.2.892| msbuild 14 | Java SE Development Kit 8 | .NET Framework 4.6.2 | SonarC# 6.8.1

[image: VM Results]
[image: VM Results - Code]
**windows 10(localhost) Install Info is...**
sonarqube-6.7.1 | sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778 | sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.0.2.892| msbuild 14 | Java SE Development Kit 8 | .NET Framework 4.7 | SonarC# 6.8.1

[image: localhost Results]
[image: localhost Results - Code]

Comment: I also installed the sonarqube plugin *CodeCracker for C#* and *SonarC#*.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify your scenario: you analyzed with two different _instances_ of SonarQube? Or just ran the analysis from two different machines, both submitting their reports to the same SonarQube instance? Also, were your analysis methods, parameters the same both times?

Comment: @ G. Ann - SonarSource Team , I edited the question, pls check again thx.

Comment: We need analysis logs to help you.

Comment: @ Julien H. - SonarSource Team I added the log info.thx

Comment: @袁于婷 Did you find a solution to your problem?